# Can Scala collection's seq/par/view/force be seen as a violation of the uniform return type principle?

Tags: c#, linq, scala, collections, types

Most of the implementation complexity of the collection framework arises from the fact, that Scala can - unlike C#'s LINQ or other collection frameworks - return the "best" collection type for higher order functions:

```
val numbers = List(1,2,3,4,5)
numbers map (2*) // returns a List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)

val doubles = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
doubles filter (_ < 3) // returns Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0)
```

Why does this principle not hold for methods like `seq`, `par`, `view`, `force`?

```
numbers.view.map(2*).force 
// returns Seq[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)

numbers.seq 
// returns scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

doubles.par.seq 
// returns scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[Double] = ArraySeq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Is there a technical limitation which prevents it from working?
Or is this by design/intent?
Considering that LINQ is basically lazy, Scala's equivalent (`view`, `force`) isn't more type-safe (only when using the strict methods), right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to embed more type information into the parallel collection classes so that you get back the collection you've started from, that's true. This would mean that after turning a `List` into a `ParVector` by calling `par` (in O(n), because elements are copied into the vector) and then calling `seq`, you would again get a `List`. To obtain the list with `seq`, you would have to copy all the elements from the vector back into the list. What happens instead is:

- `ParVector` gets converted back into a `Vector` when `seq` is called - it gets converted in O(1)
- calling `par` again on this vector will give you a `ParVector` in O(1), since they both vector and the parallel vector share the same underlying data

Notice that a collection such as a list has to be restructured when turned into a parallel collection, otherwise the operations on it cannot be efficiently parallelized.

Thus, you don't have to repetitively pay for copying when calling `par` and `seq` - the conversions become much more efficient. Since the primary goal of parallel collections was to increase efficiency, this was deemed more important than the uniform return type principle.

Comment: What about `lazy`/`view`? Are there comparable problems round that?
E. g. why does  `Vector(1,2,3).view.map(2*).force` return `Seq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 6)`?

Comment: Off the top of my head, this should be due to `map` - the type information is lost when the implicit `CanBuildFrom` found in the `SeqView` companion object gets resolved. My guess is that the `canBuildFrom` method there could be refined to take an additional type parameter `ForcedCollection` and put it into the target type of the `CanBuildFrom` - `SeqView[A, ForcedCollection]` instead of `SeqView[A, Seq[_]]`. I haven't played around with this to see if it works, though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the static return type of a collection method, C# supports overloading of LINQ extension methods (`Select`, `Where` etc.) and will automatically pick the most specific one in scope. So `Seq.Select` can return a`Seq`, `Enumerable.Select` can return an `Enumerable` etc. This is very similar to how the most specific implicit implementation is chosen in Scala.

Regarding the dynamic type, LINQ operations are implemented as extension methods so no dynamic dispatch is performed. So, `(Seq as Enumerable).Select` will return an `Enumerable`, not a `Seq`. In Scala, collection method invocations are dynamically dispatched, so the dynamic type will stay the same for `map`, `filter` etc. Both approaches have advantages/disadvantages. The only clean solution for this kind of problem is multimethods IMHO and neither language/runtime supports them efficiently.

As for runtime behaviour, LINQ always returns a lazily evaluated view of the collection. There is no method on the view which magically returns a collection of the original type, you manually have to specify that you want an array for example using the `toArray` method. IMHO, this is a cleaner and simpler approach than the one in Scala, and lazy collection operations compose better than strict ones, but this comes at the cost of an extra method call to get a strict collection for single collection operations.

Comment: I think the problem with the dynamic type is that C#'s type system is not powerful enough to compute it. Providing the same functionality as Scala would require defining and implementing every single method with the right return type for every single collection class. This is just not practical in C# (or Java).